# Navigation Drawer in a google maps activity

Tags: android, navigation, drawer

I'm exploring ways on how codes work in android and I'm a beginner. I'm wondering how can you add navigation drawer since you can't add widgets in the .xml file of the google map. Is it possible to add navigation drawer?

Also is it possible to add a button and put the codes in MapsActivity.java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would not add the navigation drawer to the *inside* of the Google map, but you could certainly have an `Activity` that hosted both a Google map and a navigation drawer.